# Repeat numbers in list N times

Tags: bash

I have a list in a text file like this: 1 2 3 4 5

I'm trying to repeat each number in the list a certain number of times, such that if N=2, then my list would become 1 1 2 2 3 3 4 4 5 5

I've been trying to use the seq command, but haven't had any luck. Is there an efficient way to do this?

Comment: Oops, you forgot to post your code! StackOverflow is about helping people fix their code, and learn how to improve their skills. It's not a free coding service. Any code is better than no code at all. Meta-code, even, will demonstrate how you're thinking a program should work, even if you don't know how to write it. Or if you're starting from somewhere past zero, show us your work so far in an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), the result you were expecting and the results you got, and we'll help you figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ N=3; echo 1 2 3 4 5 | tr ' ' \\n | sed "$(yes p | sed $((N-1))q)" | tr \\n ' '; echo
1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 3 4 4 4 5 5 5
```

Answer (score 0):

```
N=2; cat yourfile.txt | awk -v n=$N '{for(i=1; i<=NF; i++) for(j=1; j<=n; j++) printf i OFS}'
```

Answer (score 0):

As elegant as `awk` is, you don't need it for this. In bash alone, the following might do:

```
$ n=2; a=( {1..5} )
$ for i in "${a[@]}"; do eval printf \"\$i%.0s \" {1..$n}; done; echo
1 1 2 2 3 3 4 4 5 5
```

This works by placing the elements to be repeated in an array, then stepping through that array, using `printf` to repeat the current element of the `for` loop through a evaluated sequence expression. The `eval` is required here because you can't use variables inside sequence expressions.

It's not the prettiest way to go, but it works and is certainly *short*.  A longer and safer approach might be to replace the sequence expression with another for loop:

```
$ for i in "${a[@]}"; do for ((j=1; j<=$n; j++)); do printf '%s ' "$i"; done; done; echo
```

This approach mimics the `awk` solutions that have already been presented.

If you don't want to use array elements, you could achieve similar results by splitting a string on `IFS` into positional parameters. More detailed requirements in the question would help us make a recommendation.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple solution in Bash only:

```
#!/bin/bash
n=2
while read -r -n1 char; do  # read one character instead of the whole line
    count=0
    while (( $count < $n )); do
        echo -n $char
        ((count++))
    done
done < myfile.txt
```

Output: 1122334455

Answer (score 0):

I would like to do

```
echo 1 2 3 4 5 | sed -r 's/([^ ]*)/\1 \1/g'
```

But how can I do it when I don't know how often? How to repeat n times?
It should be something like `printf '\\1 %.0s' $(seq $n)`.

I can embed this in a sed command by faking a command file:

```
echo 1 2 3 4 5 | sed -rf <(echo 's/([^ ]*)/'$(printf '\\1 %.0s' $(seq $n))'/g') | tr -s ' '
```